# Ajax call always end up in error handler

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, error-handling

I am trying to get a text value('selected crate') from the server using an ajax call. Ajax call is:

```
var selected_crate ='';

$.ajax({
    url: OC.linkTo('crate_it', 'ajax/bagit_handler.php')+'?action=get_crate',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'text/html',
    success: function(data){
        selected_crate = data.responseText;
        $('#crates option').filter(function(){
            return $(this).attr("id") == selected_crate;
        }).prop('selected', true);
    },
    error: function(data){
        var e = data.responseText;
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

And the server side code snippet is:

```
case 'get_crate':
    $msg = $bagit_manager->getSelectedCrate();
    print $msg;
    break;
```

I want to do something upon success but this call always end up in error handler. If there were complete handler, it would go in that handler. But I want to use both success and error handlers because I want to

1. Send error response if something is wrong from the server side
2. Do something on success in the client side

I am struggling to achieve this. Why this call always end up in error handler and how can I actually send an error response with regard to this call that would end up in error handler if any error occurs otherwise success response?

Comment: What's the status code of the response?

Comment: Status is 200 and status text is "OK"

Comment: Have you tried removing the `dataType` option? `'text/html'` is not a valid value anyway afaik.

Comment: Yep you are right. It works when I remove the dataType. So what's the actual data type? I am curios... Thanks very much Felix

Comment: It tells jQuery which format the response is in, so that jQuery can do some pre-processing for you. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (look for `dataType` in the option list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL is right then try this:

```
dataType: "html"
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

see if in error handler data is been retrieved or not if data is been retrieved correctly it means your data-type is not matched for response in ajax call [see your server code that it must be returning some extra values in that case]

Comment: Data is being retrieved correctly so I guess it's data-type mismatch. How to find out what the data type is? Anyway from server side, as you can see, I print a text message. Don't know what php does in the background.

Answer (score 0):

url: OC.linkTo('crate_it', 'ajax/bagit_handler.php')+'?action=get_crate',

in place of this try directly url like

url: www.yoursite.com/ajax/bagit_handler.php?action=get_crate

i think it will help you to get Sucess.